# Multiprocessing of a function with numpy array as input

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a function call data_transform. It takes 2-D numpy array as the input. How I can parallize this data transformation function?

```
df = {'col2': ['a','a','b','a','b','a','a'],'col3': ['a1', 'a2','a2','a1','a1','a2','a1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
L1 = df.values  
L1 = np.transpose(L1) 
print(L1)

def data_transform(L1):
    global L3
    L3 = []
    RV = []
    for i in range(len(L1)):
       Qual_RV = list(set(L1[i]))
       Qual_RV = np.array(Qual_RV)
       RV.append(Qual_RV)
       index = np.array([],dtype=int)
       for j in range(0,len(L1[i])):
           x = np.where( Qual_RV == L1[i][j] ) 
           index = np.append(index, x[0][0])

       mask_array = np.zeros((len(L1[i]), len(Qual_RV))) 
       index1  = np.array([np.arange(len(L1[i])),index])  

       flat_index_array = np.ravel_multi_index(index1,mask_array.shape)
       np.ravel(mask_array)[flat_index_array] = 1
       mm = np.array(mask_array).tolist()  
       L3.append(mm) 
    return L3

data_transform(L1)
print(L3)
```

Comment: Check out the [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) example. You could start by creating a function to handle a single iteration from `for i in range(len(L1)):`. Does order matter in `L3` and `RV`?

Comment: Don't resort to multiprocessing until you have gotten the best performance out of `data_transform`.  Without going into details, I see two levels of iteration, and `np.append` in the inner most.  That's a big red flag!

Comment: It seems that what you try to achieve can be done simply by `pd.get_dummies`, all your function can be replaced by `L3 = [pd.get_dummies(df[col]).values.tolist() for col in df.columns]` and I think you can find more efficient function. One difference you may get is because when you create `Qual_RV` with `set`, it is unordered so I don't have the same order between `a1` and `a2` for `col3` with your function and `get_dummies`